# Как предотвратить ввода пустоты в строку

Tags: c, строки

Хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог ввести пустую строку в мой массив s(т.е. просто нажать enter), но не понимаю, как это реализовать. Пробовал сравнивать содержимое массива с нуль терминатором и вообще с пустотой(""), но ничего не выходит.

```
int main() {
    char s[SIZE];
    puts("Введите строку:");
    fgets(s, SIZE, stdin);
    if (s[SIZE] = "") {
        printf("Перезапустите программу и введите строку символов!");
        return 1;
    } /*Предотвращение ввода пустой строки*/
    int n;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых вы не сравниваете, а пытаетесь присвоить. И пытаетесь присвоить элементу за пределами массива!

```
if (s[SIZE] = "") // присвоение !!!
```

Во-вторых, чтобы строки сравнивались по содержимому используют `strcmp()`. Сравнивая 'if("" == "")' в общем случае вы получите отрицательный результат, т.к. сравниваются указатели на строки, а строки - разные.

```
if ( strcmp( s, "") == 0 )
```

Второй вариант. Как понять размер строки? - строка ограничивается нулём. Что такое пустая строка? Это значит ноль стоит на первом месте. Т.е. проверьте первый символ строки на ноль.

```
if ( s[0] == 0 )
```

Иногда при вводе пустой строки с клавиатуры она на самом деле может состоять из 2 символов - "\n\0" Проверьте дебаггером. Тогда надо будет

```
if ( s[0] == '\n' and s[1] == 0 )
```

Comment: функция `fgets` возвращает перевод строки не иногда, а почти всегда. Пустую строку он может вернуть при чтении с потока, который связан с пустым файлом. И если просто обрубить входной поток Ctrl+D, то вернёт вообще нулевой указатель. Короче надо добавить `if (fgets(..) == NULL)` типа входной поток закрыт.